# How prove this $\max_i|\textbf{p}_i(t)|\leq \max_i|\textbf{p}_i(0)|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let 
$$\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}=1, \ \ \ \ i=1,\dots,N$$
and consider
$$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{p}_i=\bar{\textbf{p}}_i-\textbf{p}_i, \ \ \ \bar{\textbf{p}}_i:=\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} \textbf{p}_j.$$
Prove that
$$\max_i|\textbf{p}_i(t)|\leq \max_i|\textbf{p}_i(0)|.$$

Comment: Have you ever heard of Gronwall's inequality?

Comment: @Jeb, No, I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to differential inequalities, you need to add Gronwall's inequality to your belt. If
$$ \frac{d}{dt} y \leq  p(t) y$$
then you may conclude (where existence permits)
$$ y(t) \leq y(a) \exp \left (\int_a^t p(s) ds \right)$$
Note that with your condition on $A$ you have
$$\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} p_j \leq \max_{i}|p_i|$$ 
Skipping over a few technical details (which you should verify), we'll see (from your original differential inequality)
$$\frac{d}{dt} \max_{i}|p_i| \leq 0$$
Thus
$$\max_{i}|p_i| \leq \max_{i} | p_i(0)| $$

Comment: Thank you, but why $\frac{d}{dt} \max_{i}|p_i| \leq 0$?

Comment: This falls somewhat into the technical bits... but basically because you have for every $i$ that $\frac{d}{dt} p_i \leq \max |p_i| - p_i$, so try to show that we may claim $\frac{d}{dt} \max_i |p_i| \leq \max | p_i| - \max | p_i| \leq 0$. Of course we're glancing over possible jumps of the derivative, and we added the abs...just wanted to sketch the argument for you.